# Java help 25% of time

Tags: java, math, plugins, minecraft

I am working on developing a minecraft plugin based on the Movie InTime. When a player kills you you are susposed to lose 25% of your time and drop it in the form of a TimeCard (Book). The player who killed you can then pick up the TimeCard and use it.

Currently the plugin is only attempting to get the players years, multiply them by 25% and then issue the command to remove 25 years from the player. (y tells the server to take years not days, weeks, hours)

Here is the code for it:

```
  Integer time = itapi.getPlayerYears(player.getName());
  Double remove = Integer.valueOf(time) * 0.25;
  String minus = String.valueOf(remove) + 'y' ;
  itapi.removeTime(player.getName(), itapi.getDeathTime());
  ItemStack book = itapi.createTimeCard("Death of " + player.getName(), minus, 1);
  itapi.removeTime(player.getName(), minus);
  e.getDrops().add(book);
```

though when a player gets killed this error is thrown:

http://pastebin.com/0aqSV37S

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.25"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) ~[?:1.7.0]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) ~[?:1.7.0]
        at com.BlackMage.InTime2.InTime2API.removeTime(InTime2API.java:551) ~[?:?]
```

I am beyond confused on how to resolve these errors and after trying several different things am looking for some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look lower in the stack trace, you'll see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.25"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492) ~[?:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527) ~[?:1.7.0]
    at com.BlackMage.InTime2.InTime2API.removeTime(InTime2API.java:551) ~[?:?]
    at com.BlackMage.InTime2.DeathListener.onDeath(DeathListener.java:37) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0]
```

Look at the removeTime method in InTime2API (on line 551, or just find a line that tries to call `parseInt` in that method). If you want the parse to succeed, you'll need to do `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` and store the result in a float variable.

Comment: `for (String x : amount.split(" ")) {
      if (x.endsWith("y"))
        ay = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("y", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("w"))
        aw = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("w", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("d"))
        ad = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("d", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("h"))
        ah = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("h", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("m"))
        am = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("m", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("s")) {
        as = Integer.parseInt(x.replace("s", ""));
      }`

Comment: Should be: `for (String x : amount.split(" ")) {
      if (x.endsWith("y"))
        ay = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("y", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("w"))
        aw = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("w", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("d"))
        ad = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("d", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("h"))
        ah = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("h", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("m"))
        am = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("m", ""));
      else if (x.endsWith("s")) {
        as = Integer.parseFloat(x.replace("s", ""));
      }`

Comment: It would actually be "Float.parseFloat"

Comment: That worked Thank you! now to fix it so that it converts the decimal down to weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 3):

somewhere in your code you are parsing a `String` to `int`, and it attempts for `1.25` which isn't an `int` so the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.25"
```

Comment: @user how do you know

Comment: educated guess - he multiplies an int (5 in this case) by 0.25, so he probably didn't think through the typing of these things very well (the second call to removeTime is probably at fault, i assume it parses string as int)